# Access dom-repeat inside a dom-if from javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to access a `dom-repeat` that is present inside a `dom-if` from JavaScript?

```
<template is="dom-if" if={{someCondition}}>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items={{data}}></template>
</template>
```

I can access the `dom-if` using `this.$.id`, but how can I access the `dom-repeat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `this.$$(selector)` function of the [DOM API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding). As per the docs

> $$ returns the first node in the local DOM that matches selector.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'my-elem',
  
  accessSelector: function() {
    alert(this.$$('div').textContent);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <my-elem></my-elem>
  
  <dom-module id="my-elem">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-if" if="true">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items='[ 1, 2, 3 ]'>
          <div>Item: {{item}}</div>
        </template>
      </template>
      
      <button on-tap="accessSelector">Selector</button>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post it with working code snippet. I've already tried `this.$$('id')`.

Comment: Just to make sure: if you're selecting by ID, you'd have to put a '#' in front of it: this.$$('#id')

Comment: I added a snippet with the use of `$$`.

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz thanks for the help. From your snippet i was finally able to figure out the issue with my code. It was because `dom-if` was false to begin with. I've made edit to your answer hope you don't mind.

Comment: @elliot I am aware of adding `#` in front of the id but still, thanks for the tip.